# How can I create a HashMap in DataWeave2 inside a transformation in Mule 4?

Tags: hashmap, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I need to make a HashMap inside a transform Message in Mule 4 to send to a service.

I was trying to make something like this:

```
 %dw 2.0
 import HasMap from java!java::util::HashMap
 output application/java
 ---
 HasMap ( <'data': write(payload, "application/json")>,
 <'attribute1': 'att1'>,
 <'attribute2': 'att2'>,
 <'attribute3': 'att3'> )
```

because as I successfully created a string using java libraries, I think that I can do the same for HashMap, but it is still not working:

```
 %dw 2.0
 import valueOf from java!java::lang::String
 output application/java
 ---
 valueOf({
 data: write(payload, "application/json"),
 atrribute1: 'att1',
 atrribute2: 'att2',
 atrribute3: 'att3'       })
```

At the beginning, I tried just to map like this:

```
 %dw 2.0
 output application/java
 ---
 {

 "data": write(payload, "application/json"),
 "attribute1": "att1",
 "attribute2": "att2",
 "attribute3": "att3"

 }
```

but the problem is that the service received something like this:

'\xac\xed\x00\x05sr\x00\x17java.util.LinkedHashMap4\xc0N\\x10l\xc0\xfb\x02\x00\x01Z\x00\x0baccessOrderxr\x00\x11java.util.HashMap\x05\x07\xda\xc1\xc3\x16`\xd1\x03\x00\x02F\x00\nloadFI\x00\tthresholdxp?@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0cw\x08\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x06t\x00\x04datat\x06\x19{\n "data": "{}", "attribute1": "att1",.....'

Any ideas of how can I create a normal Hash Map?

I expect to receive:

'data': '{....}', 'attribute1': 'att1','attribute2': 'att2', 'attribute3': 'att3'

Comment: you will need to map to `application/json` in the beginning and check the output

Comment: Clearly the service is receiving a Java HashMap and not liking it. Usually you should send a JSON as @Ven mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

So if you want the output to be a "java.util.HashMap" instance then you need to use

```
%dw 2.0
 output application/java
 ---
 {

 "data": write(payload, "application/json"),
 "attribute1": "att1",
 "attribute2": "att2",
 "attribute3": "att3"

 } as Object {class : "java.util.HashMap"}
```

Though I don't think this is what you really want as HashMap is not something you want to try to a service, most probable you want all to be a json and that is being done by using **output application/json**